# Failure to install C extension of a third party library at GAE python Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine-python

I've deployed my application on the Google App Engine python flexible runtime environment.
I thought to use a library (named as shap) which used to retrieve feature importance from the Random Forest model. I've mentioned its name in the requirement.txt while deploying to app engine. 
I also noticed that the installation of c extension(dependency of shap library) has mentioned in the setup file of shap library. 
Google Cloud App Engine (Flexible) is supposed to install this library with all dependencies including c extension, but when I run my application on the app engine, it starts getting following error:

> name '_cext' is not defined.

here _cext is a c extension.
This library is working fine locally. It seems it has a problem with the app engine flexible environment. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How is that extension normally installed? How did you install it on your local system?

Comment: C extension is a partial dependency of shap library. I'm getting the same error as you can see in the following link:

Comment: sorry about unfinish comment. C extension is a partial dependency of shap library installation process,  I'm getting the same error in google cloud, as it define in the following link: [https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/96](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/96). The difference is in local it has been resolved. I don't even know whether google cloud can adapt third party library which is using C language file as an extension or not.

Answer (score 1):

If the solution used locally relies exclusively on `pip` commands you may be able to use `requirements.txt` file options, see [Requirements File Format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format).

But if you need something else besides executing `pip` operations then you probably have to build a custom runtime, see [Up-to-date pip with AppEngine Python flex env?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338170/up-to-date-pip-with-appengine-python-flex-env/52340904#52340904)