# Problem with nltk during app deployment on google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, nltk

I tried to deploy my application on gcloud app engine, when the deployment finish and  I tried to brows the URL, I got 502 server error. The log shows that there is problem with nltk package:

```
[31m>>> import nltk 
   >>> nltk.download('punkt') 
   [0m 
   Searched in: 
     - '/root/nltk_data' 
     - '/usr/share/nltk_data' 
     - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data' 
     - '/usr/lib/nltk_data' 
     - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data' 
     - '/env/nltk_data' 
     - '/env/lib/nltk_data' 
     - ''
```

I have put the necessary hardware requirement on my app.yaml file :

```
service: vapi
runtime: python
env: flex
health_check:
    enable_health_check: True
    check_interval_sec: 5
    timeout_sec: 4
    unhealthy_threshold: 2
    healthy_threshold: 2
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT wsgi:app
runtime_config:
    python_version: 3.5
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 8
  disk_size_gb: 20
```

I have tried to install the nltk packages into one of the search path shown in the log above.

also, I have created app engine configuration file:

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up the documentation for the standard environment with the one for the flexible environment.

Installing dependencies into the `lib` directory and using a `appengine_config.py` file is [specific for the 1st generation standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library).

For the flexible environment you specify your python dependencies using the `requirements.txt` file, see [Using Python Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries):

> The Python runtime will [automatically install](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#dependencies) all dependencies
>   declared in your `requirements.txt` during deployment.

For non-python dependencies or those which aren't pip-installable you can use a custom runtime, see [Up-to-date pip with AppEngine Python flex env?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52338170/up-to-date-pip-with-appengine-python-flex-env/52340904#52340904)

Maybe of interest: [How to tell if a Google App Engine documentation page applies to the 1st/2nd generation standard or the flexible environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842772/how-to-tell-if-a-google-app-engine-documentation-page-applies-to-the-1st-2nd-gen)