# Google Cloud Client Libraries in Python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-client

I have been using Google Cloud Client Libraries for my project and getting import errors.

> Import Error: No module named cloud

I have ***app.yaml*** in my project which looks like the following:

```
runtime: python27

api_version: 1
threadsafe: no

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main
```

Now I have configured **requirements.txt** which has **google-cloud-datastore** and **google-cloud-storage**

*requirements.txt*

```
Flask==1.0.2
google-cloud-datastore
google-cloud-storage
google-api-python-client
```

Now when I import google.cloud in my main.py file I get the import error.

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

I have deployed the project on **Google App Engine**

After getting errors I changed my Project to Python 3.7 and then deployed on App Engine and to my surprise, it worked perfectly.

So is it because **google-api-python-client** is deprecated in Python 2.7 or am I doing something wrong in here

Comment: also note the difference between how you dependencies are managed in the 2 generations of the standard environment - `requirements.txt` is needed and sufficient in 3.7, but not in 2.7, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56111441/4495081

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `google-cloud-storage` doesn't support App Engine Standard environment for Python 2.7. Fortunately, Google Cloud provide an alternative for Python 2.7. So, to use Google cloud storage, you need to install [GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#activating_a_cloud_storage_bucket).

In lib's parent directory, use this command:

```
pip install -t lib GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient
```

Then, you can import `cloudstorage` like this:

```
import cloudstorage
```

Please find [the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample): The example was elaborate with `webapp2` but it works with Flask.